# Intellij and Hybris Tests

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, sap-commerce-cloud

Currently I'm doing the hybris 5 Developer Training Trails 5.7 - Part I - Core in Intellij and the Hybris Plugin for Intellij.

Now I'm at the point where I have to run a test class. When I'm doing it, it tells me that it's not finding a a class "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.jalo.Match".
When I'm running the same test in http://localhost:9001/test then everything works fine.

I guess I have to fix my classpath, but I don't know how. If I change the classpath of the module in "Run/Debug Configurations" to something else, then it's not working. If I change there the working directory from MODULES_DIR to the whole project path it's not working either. Now I have no ideas anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just install ["Hybris Integration"](https://bitbucket.org/AlexanderBartash/impex-editor-intellij-idea-plugin/overview) plugin it will do everything automatically. You will be able to import Hybris projects just like maven or gradle based projects. That plugin provides Hybris integration into Intellij IDEA and another IDE based on it.

You can install it to your IDE directly from the [repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525) by clicking on the "Browse Repositories" button in Settings/Plugins dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all your JAVA Build Path Problems. Then test cases should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had set the "power save mode" on IntelliJ. Removing it solved the problem for testing